# Как в Prestashop изменить .tpl модуля

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Prestasop vers:1.7.6.8

Модуль: tvсmegamenu

Расскажите, как мне tpl файл поменять? Я хочу изменить html и только...

В файле my_project/modules/tvcmsmegamenu/views/templates/hook/display_menu.tpl ничего не помогает

Прошу помощи в просветлении :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы переопределить `tpl` модуля, вам нужно скопировать структуру папок и файл, который вы хотите переопределить, в свою тему.

Например, если вы хотите изменить `display_menu.tpl` и у вас есть тема под названием `yourthemename` вам нужно будет скопировать:

`/modules/tvcmsmegamenu/views/templates/hook/display_menu.tpl` в

```
/themes/yourthemename/modules/tvcmsmegamenu/views/templates/hook/display_menu.tpl
```

Так же не забудьте проверить кэш и изменить настройки рекомпиляции смарти шаблонов в настройках престашопа:

```
Advanced Parameters -> Performance -> enable recompilation of template
```

Comment: А как изменить данные, попадаемые в модуль?